# setup.py - packages in requirements reinstalled despite being already present

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py, appveyor

In my appveyor .ylm, I am installing a specific version of a package, for example:

```
- cmd: conda install future=0.16.0
```

It gets installed without any problem.

The issue is that the package is also a dependency of one of the packages in my requirements.txt file, and appveyor reinstalls it from pypi.

As a matter of fact, all packages in my requirements.txt are reinstalled, as if they could not be found.

Is this expected behaviour? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Are you certain `conda` and `pip` are both in the same environment?

Comment: @NilsWerner Indeed: I use conda to set up the environment and install packages in the dependency list, but install my own package using pip as what I have is a setup.py file.